# iOS Mapkit crash when using selectannotation

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, mapkit, segmentation-fault

I am having trouble figuring out the cause of this crash.

I have an iPad application with a MapView and Tableview on the same screen. I am trying to allow the user to select a row in the table to then highlight the corresponding pin in the map or vice versa.  In the simulator it works fine.  On the device it works for a while, but then if I keep doing it will crash with a SIGSEGV. I can't figure out why.

It seems to happen only when going from the selected tableview row to selecting the pin in the mapview.

Here is the code

```
  Place *p = [self.results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSArray *annon = [self.mapView annotations];
for ( int i = 0; i < [annon count]; i++)
{
      NSObject *a = [annon objectAtIndex:i];
      if ([a isKindOfClass:PlaceAnnotation.class])
      {
           PlaceAnnotation *pa = (PlaceAnnotation *)a;
           if (p.placeid == pa.placeid)
           {  
                [self.mapView selectAnnotation:pa animated:YES];
                break;
           }
      }
}
```

Here is the type of crashes we are seeing as a result of executing this code.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x9
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x317c4f78 0x317c1000 + 16248
1   CoreFoundation                      0x3195576b 0x318c6000 + 587627
2   CoreFoundation                      0x318cd644 0x318c6000 + 30276
3   CoreFoundation                      0x318cf701 0x318c6000 + 38657
4   MapKit                              0x36b061f3 0x36ab9000 + 315891
5   MapKit                              0x36acf33d 0x36ab9000 + 90941
6   MapKit                              0x36acf2f1 0x36ab9000 + 90865
7   MapKit                              0x36ad29bd 0x36ab9000 + 104893
8   MapKit                              0x36acdf03 0x36ab9000 + 85763
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: were you able to figure it out? I think I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the crash is because of the current location bubble that appears as soon as the accurate position is found. Try disabling the user location using the following

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
```

If you are in need of user location, include the following delegate method and check whether the app crashes.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation {
if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceAnnotation class]]) {
    return nil;
}
```

}

Thanks.